Core generado en un programa en C en sistema operativo Ubuntu
Este programa se compila satisfactoriamente. Sin embargo, al
ejecutarlo, produce un error:

"Violación de segmentación.Core generado".

#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int argc,char *argv[])
{
    system("clear");
    setlocale(LC_ALL,"spanish");
    int n,i,j;
    double interpol,*suma =0,*producto=NULL;
    double *x[10],*y[10];   
     {
        printf("¿Cuántos números quiere introducir? :");
         scanf("%d",&n);
         x[10] = (double *) malloc(100*sizeof(double));
         y[10] = (double *) malloc(100*sizeof(double));
         producto = (double *) malloc(100*sizeof(double));
         suma = (double *) malloc(100*sizeof(double));
         interpol = (double *) malloc(300*sizeof(double));
         
         for(i = 1;i <= n ; ++i) {
              printf("Introduzca los valores de orden %2d :\n",i);
              printf("Introduzca el valor de x :");
              scanf("%p",x+i);
              printf("Introduzca el valor de y :");
              scanf("%p",y+i);
        }
     printf("Introduzca el valor que desea interpolar :");
     scanf("%p",interpol);
     
     
     for(i=1; i <=n;++i)
              {
                   *producto = 1;
                   for (j = 1;j <= n;++j)
                        {
                             if(i!=j)
                             *producto = *producto*(interpol-(*x[j])/(*x[i])-(*x[j]));
                        }
                   *producto = *producto* * y[i];
                   *suma = *suma + *producto;
              }
         printf("El número buscado es : %p\n",suma);
  return 0;
  }
}


Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera medalla! Cuando intentas introducir que cosa donde??? no sabemos nada de tu programa...

Hola Francesc, es imposible que podamos ayudar con solo eso, suponiendo que tienes un segmentation fault hay muchas causas posibles. Sin más información y especialmente sin el código no vamos a poder decirte nada concreto. Edita la pregunta y agrega el código o al menos un [mcve] . El código simplemente lo  copias, lo pegas en la pregunta, seleccionas todo el código pegado y pulsas Ctrl + K o el botón {} del editor para formatearlo. Si tienes problemas con el formateo no te preocupes, déjalo como puedas y te ayudaremos  después.

Ahora estamos mejor, pero por favor, explica tamben cuando te da el problema...

El error se produce en scanf("%p",interpol).

Pero si interpol es valor double deberías usar scanf("%lf", &interpol);

Gracias, Synay. Modifico, declarando interpol como puntero, y la instrucción quedaría así : scan("%lf",interpol). Al depurar el programa, el error se produce en la instrucción  *producto = producto(interpol-(*x[j])/(*x[i])-(*x[j]));

Ese error siempre se produce cuando intentas acceder a una posición de memoria que no deberías.
Por empezar, declaras 2 arreglos de 10 punteros:
double *x[10],*y[10];

Sin embargo, intentas escribir en la posición 10 y está mal! Los arreglos comienzan por 0 y terminan en N-1 (9 en este caso).
x[10] = (double *) malloc(100*sizeof(double));
y[10] = (double *) malloc(100*sizeof(double));

Posteriormente, entiendo que quieres leer un valor númerico. Pero por qué lo lees con %p? Si quieres un double tienes que usar %lf y pasarle un puntero a dónde quieres que se guarde.
printf("Introduzca el valor de x :");
scanf("%p",x+i);
printf("Introduzca el valor de y :");
scanf("%p",y+i);

Lo mismo pasa con scanf("%p",interpol);. Definitivamente debes tener alguna confusión respecto a los punteros.
Arreglando un poco el código, así debería funcionar.
#include <stdio.h>
#include <locale.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    system("clear");
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "spanish");

    int n, i, j;
    double interpol, suma = 0, producto = 1;
    double *x, *y;

    printf("¿Cuántos números quiere introducir? : ");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    x = (double *)malloc(n * sizeof(double));
    y = (double *)malloc(n * sizeof(double));

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        printf("Introduzca los valores de orden %2d :\n", i + 1);
        printf("Introduzca el valor de x : ");
        scanf("%lf", &x[i]);
        printf("Introduzca el valor de y : ");
        scanf("%lf", &y[i]);
    }

    printf("Introduzca el valor que desea interpolar : ");
    scanf("%lf", &interpol);

    for (i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        producto = 1;
        for (j = 0; j < n; ++j)
        {
            if (i != j)
                producto *= (interpol - x[j]) / (x[i] - x[j]);
        }
        producto *= y[i];
        suma += producto;
    }

    printf("El número buscado es: %.2lf\n", suma);

    free(x);
    free(y);

    return 0;
}


Hola,Mateo. Lo primero,tengo que agradecerte tu respuesta, que además de solucionar el problema, permites que aprenda conceptos.No te doy la razón en una cosa, porque no es que tenga alguna confusión con los punteros,sino que no tenía ni idea, Gracias a tu respuesta ya no es así. De verdad, muy agradecido

@Francesc si te sirvió mí respuesta, puedes marcarla ✅ para que más personas puedan encontrarla. Siempre es buena idea leer la documentación de las funciones. La de scanf te será útil. Aprovecho a sugerirte revisar un problema muy común antes que lo descubras por tu cuenta y mostrarte formas de resolverlo.

Tu respuesta me ha sido útil y la he marcado.La califico considero muy pedagógica.Gracias por tus sugerencias.Leeré los enlaces.Saludos
